HTML page to PDF using pdfkit in python django returning blank
I am trying to convert an html file to pdf after passing and populating it with some data. But it is returning a blank white page.I am using pdfkit and django and below is my code.
def generate_pdf(data):
    """
        Convert HTML content to PDF.
    """
    html_string = render_to_string('timeline_template.html', {'data': data})
    pdf_file = pdfkit.from_string(html_string, False)
    return pdf_file


Also below is the html page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Timeline Report</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>

        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          background: rgb(245,245,245);
          color: rgb(50,50,50);
          font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
          font-size: 14px;
          line-height: 1.6em;
        }

        /* Timeline container */
        .timeline {
          position: relative;
          width: 80%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          margin-top: 20px;
          padding: 1em 0;
          list-style-type: none;
        }

        /* Vertical line on the left */
        .timeline:before {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          left: 40px;
          top: 0;
          width: 2px;
          height: 100%;
          background: rgb(230,230,230);
        }

        /* Individual timeline items */
        .timeline li {
          padding: 20px 0;
          position: relative;
        }

        /* Circle markers */
        .timeline li:before {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          left: 31.5px;
          top: 24px;
          width: 16px;
          height: 16px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background: white;
          border: 2px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        }


        .timeline li .desc ul{
          margin-left: 0;
          padding-left: 0;
          list-style: none;
        }

        .timeline li .desc ul li{
          position: relative;
        }

        .timeline li .desc ul li:before{
          content: none;
        }

        /* Main container for content */
        .timeline li .flag-wrapper {
          position: relative;
          margin-left: 80px;
          background: white;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }

        /* Title of the change (e.g., Date and Time) */
        .timeline li .flag {
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 16px;
          color: black;
        }

        /* Time label */
        .timeline li .time-wrapper {
          font-size: 14px;
          color: rgb(255,0,0);
        }

        /* Description or changes made */
        .timeline li .desc {
          margin-top: 10px;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: black;
          margin-left: 80px;
        }

        /* Media queries for responsiveness */
        @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
          .timeline {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
          }

          .timeline:before {
            left: 10px;
          }

          .timeline li:before {
            left: 4px;
          }

          .timeline li .flag-wrapper {
            margin-left: 40px;
          }
           .timeline li .desc{
              margin-left: 40px;

          }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
          .timeline li .flag-wrapper {
            margin-left: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
          }

          .timeline li .flag {
            font-size: 14px;
          }

          .timeline li .desc {
            font-size: 13px;
            margin-left: 20px;
          }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="timeline">
        {% for item in data.result %}
        <li>
            <div class="direction-r">
                <div class="flag-wrapper">
                    <span class="flag">{{ item.date_time }}</span>
                    <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">Action By: {{ item.changed_by }}</span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    {% for action in item.actions %}
                    <h3>{{ action.sub_element }}</h3>
                        <ul>
                            {% for change in action.changes %}
                            <li>{{ change }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

There is no js.
The data is being passed correctly and is of the correct format. The thing I noticed is that if I remove the for loops and also the variables,( eg: '{{change}}') basically a static, it returns fine. Basically its the curly brace and percentage symbols causing the issue.
Is this problem of returning blank pdf common with pdfkit while using server side rendering in django (django template engine)?
What can be done?
I tried using weasyprint but it required some external libraries and I couldnt install it.
I saw something about django-weasyprint which has no issue like this I think, should i use it or stick with pdfkit?

The standard pdfkit knows nothing about Django templating.  Are you using django-pdfkit?

Thanks for the reply. No I am not using django-pdfkit. Just the standard one. Is the syntax same

I misdiagnosed your issue.  I see now that you are already passing your file through the Django templating, so there shouldn't be any Django fields left.  You should print html_string to prove that.  It looks like you have some sophisticated CSS in there; pdfkit uses wkhtmltopdf which uses the Qt Webkit, which doesn't support each and every brand new CSS feature.
